# Android scoped storage on Android 11 - permission denied

Tags: android, adb, scoped-storage

The scenario is that my app is creating some files on its external storage `/sdcard/Android/data/myPackageName` and during testing automation I need to retrieve some files from that folder using `adb`.

The `compileSdkVersion` and `targetSdkVersion` are set to `31`, and also uses:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

For some reasons, the `adb pull` command doesn't work (permission denied) on Android 11 but it works on Android 13 (I used real phones **not emulators**)

These are the mount points:

**Android 13**

```
/dev/block/dm-40 on /storage/emulated/0/Android/data type f2fs (rw,lazytime,seclabel,nosuid,nodev,noatime,background_gc=on,discard,no_heap,user_xattr,inline_xattr,acl,inline_data,inline_dentry,flush_merge,extent_cache,mode=adaptive,active_logs=6,reserve_root=32768,resuid=0,resgid=1065,inlinecrypt,alloc_mode=default,checkpoint_merge,fsync_mode=nobarrier,discard_unit=block)
```

**Android 11**

```
/dev/block/dm-12 on /storage/emulated/0/Android/data type f2fs (rw,lazytime,seclabel,nosuid,nodev,noatime,background_gc=on,discard,no_heap,user_xattr,inline_xattr,acl,inline_data,inline_dentry,flush_merge,extent_cache,mode=adaptive,active_logs=6,reserve_root=32768,resuid=0,resgid=1065,inlinecrypt,alloc_mode=default,fsync_mode=nobarrier)
```

(the only differences are: `discard_unit=block` and `checkpoint_merge`)

I read a lot of SO posts, Android documentation etc and but I wasn't able to figure out the reason why this is happening. Why it works on 13 and not on 11? Any idea?